# How to fetch media from the Instagram API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch media from an instagram account that I manage to display it on a website that I'm building:

Basically I want to run this query:

```
https://graph.instagram.com/{userId}/media?fields=id,caption,media_url&access_token=IGQ...
```

But as a response I get this error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '31044158025' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation",
        "type": "IGApiException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 33,
        "fbtrace_id": "AOdEf2mCpah6zWwkEdiZU95"
    }
}
```

I followed [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started) from the official documentation to create the app on facebook developer account, get the access token etc.

I got the {userId} going on instagram and exploring the network requests from the developer tools (is there an easier way? :D)

Any help appreciated,

Thanks!

Matteo

Comment: I have the same question, did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Hey! I found a work around to get my project going. since I was building a website in Gatsby I could install this plugin: gatsby-source-instagram https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-instagram/

They use one way to fetch the public apy and it works for them... maybe you can checkout the code of the plugin and figure out how. I think I read it but now I forgot. 

Hope it can help!